# How to load .svg format in UIButton background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, uibutton, uiimage

Am trying to load .svg image in UIButton background and its not working like the way .png or .jpeg

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.svg"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Convert it into pdf and add in assets.

Comment: there is not native support for .svg in iOS. Try https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit